# Какие знаки препинания необходимо поставить в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, приложение

Объясните, пожалуйста, какие знаки нужно поставить в данном предложении:

*Местного хулигана (—/,) Ваньку (—/,) видно издалека.*

Comment: Лучше всего ничего не ставить!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пунктуация будет зависеть от контекста и интонации (логических ударений), поэтому возможны два варианта.

**1.**  *Местного хулиг**á**на, В**á**ньку, видно издалека.* (Читается с двумя паузами.)

> 6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо уточняет нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова *а именно, то есть, а зовут его*): *Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, **Наталья Алексеевна,** с первого взгляда могла не понравиться* (Т.); *Отец мой, **Клим Торсуев,** известный мыловар, был человек тяжёлого характера* (Ж. Г.); *А братья Ани, **Петя и Андрюша,** гимназисты, дёргали отца сзади за фрак* (Ч.)...

**2.** *Местного хулигана В**á**ньку // видно издалека.* (Одна произносительная пауза.)

> **Примечание.** Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении. <...>
> *Сегодня я и друг мой **Серёжа** уезжаем на юг; Выступал староста группы **Коля Петров***...

Источник: [**Обособленные приложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) (справочник Розенталя).

P. S. Обособление с помощью тире, на мой взгляд, будет излишним.